# Groovy Grails - Problems retrieving values from Map by key

Tags: grails, groovy

Something odd is going on in the following code.  I successfully create a map, and as shown in the output I have keys and values, but I can't retrieve the values with the key.

See code and output below:

```
class HomeController {

def index() {
    List gs=Gizmo.getAll()
   def gizmoList= gs.collectEntries {
        [(it.id): (it.name)]
    }


    println "item 2 is ${gizmoList['2']}"

    println "item 2  is ${gizmoList[2]}"
    println "keyset is " + gizmoList.keySet().toList().toString()
    println "values are" + gizmoList.values().toList().toString()
    [myList: gizmoList ]
 }
}
```

the console output is:

```
item 2 is null
item 2  is null
keyset is [1, 2, 3]
values are[flange, nork, prule]
```

Somehow I think the keys maybe GStringImpl or something, but I thought putting parens around would coerce to plain strings.

Comment: `Gizmo` is Domain class, right?

Comment: It's easy to find out the key types - `println gizmoList.keySet()*.getClass()*.name`. If you're using GStrings as map keys stop. Google it, there has been a lot of discussion about why they're a problem, e.g. http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td4511883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails, `id`'s are `Long`, so your `String` and `Integer` keys are not found.

This snippet works:

```
assert "item 2  is ${gizmoList[2l]}" == "item 2  is nork"
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well Not sure but when i tried similar on groovy web console, it worked properly. See attached below:

[image: Similar code]

Hence, to me it looks like something wrong with either grails or you are doing something wrong.
Please try once more and check for any possible mistake.